# Jquery ui function level scoping

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm following along this example:
http://jqueryui.com/slider/#slider-vertical

I've copied the exact code (changing the div/input names to my own) from this example into another webpage, but chrome throws a `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` and the slider never appears.

The exact code that does not work:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#timeframe_slider" ).slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "min",
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      value: 60,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#month_week" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#month_week" ).val( $( "#timeframe_slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
```

When I change the code from what the example has to simply:

```
$( "#timeframe_slider" ).slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    value: 0,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
      if (ui.value === 0) {
        $( "#month_week" ).val("Month");
      } else {
      $( "#month_week" ).val("Week");
    }}
 });
```

it works perfectly.

I'm fairly new to javascript, but I understand that having:

```
$(function() {
    code goes here
};
```

is to ensure that the page is ready. Can someone explain why when attempting to use the example the .slider() function suddenly does not work?

**UPDATE**
This problem does not appear when trying to recreate it in jsfiddle.. Here's exactly what I'm looking at however:
[image]

Comment: is slider() the function that is undefined?

Comment: In your first example which you say doesn't work, you're missing a quote here `$("#timeframe_slider )`. Should be `$("#timeframe_slider")`

Comment: Chrome shows: $( "#timeframe_slider" ).slider({ Uncaught TypeError   Orientation:

Comment: @j08691 that was a typo. The quote is actually present. Updated the question.

Comment: I'm not clear on what the actual issue is. Seems to work fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bt5mo15x/.

Comment: Hmmm. Came across something interesting. I'm using Google hosted jquery and jquery ui. When I use those as external resources it breaks. http://jsfiddle.net/bt5mo15x/1/

Comment: Seems fine if you also remember to link in the jQuery UI CSS http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bt5mo15x/3/ (and update the input's ID)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is that you're not accidentally including jquery twice, causing the slider plugin to no longer be attached to $ when the `$(function() {` wrapped code fires.

Sorry this is more of a comment then an answer, but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet.